# How to specify the positive class manually before fitting Sklearn estimators and transformers

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I am trying to predict credit card approvals using the [relevant dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/credit+approval) from UCI ML Repo. The problem is that the target encodes the applications for credit cards as '+' for approved and '-' for rejected.

As there are a bit more rejected applications in the target, all scorers, estimators are treating the rejected class as positive while it should be otherwise. Because of this, my confusion matrix is all messed up because I think all True Positives and True Negatives, False Positives and False Negatives get inverted:

[image]

How can I specify the positive class manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know of scikit-learn estimators or transformers that let you flip positive and negative class identifiers as a parameter. But I can think of two ways to work around this:

---

**Method 1: You transform the array labels yourself before fitting the estimator**

That can be easily achieved for `numpy` arrays:

```py
y = np.array(['+', '+', '+', '-', '-'])
y_transformed = [1 if i == '+' else 0 for i in y]
```

and also pandas `Series` objects:

```py
y = pd.Series(['+', '+', '+', '-', '-'])
y_transformed = y.map({'+': 1, '-': 0})
```

In both cases the output will be `[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]`

---

**Method 2: You define the `labels` parameter in `confusion_matrix`**

scikit-learn's [`confusion_matrix`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html#sklearn-metrics-confusion-matrix) has a parameter `labels` that lets you reorder the labels. Use like this:

```py
y_true = np.array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
y_pred = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0])

print(confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred))
# output
[[2 0]
 [1 2]]


print(confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=[1, 0]))
# output
[[2 1]
 [0 2]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also found out that I could use `LabelBinarizer` because turns out you can specify the positive and negative labels manually even though it is designed for multi-class targets. But yours seems better actaully

Comment: Hello @afsharov, so not even ```XGBoost ```? We can safely assume that for all ```sklearn ``` models we only specify which labels belong to which class when we use error metrics (precision, recal, etc) and/or confusion matrices and/or ROC curves ?